# I can't find what is wrong with idel on this code

Tags: python

I wrote a code in a compiler online and it's worked but I tried exact code on IDLE and it's goes on a infinity loop. so can anyone tell me what is the problem here:

```
i = 0 
while True:
i = i + 1
if i % 2 == 0 :
    print ("hoop")
    continue
    if i >= 100 :
        print( " taMam")
        break
    print(i)
print (" Khoshet OOmad?")
```

Comment: Check you indentation. Everything after while True should be indented to the right

Comment: Please make sure you format the code correctly so that it appears here *exactly* as you have it in your actual file. This requires an *extra* four spaces in front of *each* code line. You can do this easily by pasting the entire code, selecting the *entire* code, and pressing the indent button (the one labelled `{}`).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `continue` line in your code is preventing the code that might end the loop from ever running. In particular, these lines looks very suspicious:

```
continue
if i >= 100 :
    print( " taMam")
    break
```

If this code runs, the `continue` will cause the loop body to restart, and the `if` will never run. It's not entirely clear if this is actually how the code is formatted on your end, or if the indentation might have been mixed up in copying the code into Stack Overflow. But given that you describe the loop as running forever, I suspect this is your error.

Probably you should just remove the `continue` line. Most loops run to the end of the indented block, after which they'll start from the top again automatically. You only need to use `continue` in special situations, where you want to restart the loop early.

I usually use continue as an alternative to a big `if` block. That is, rather than this (imagine that `do_lots_of_stuff_here()` is many lines of code, maybe with nested loops or `if` blocks, not just a single function call):

```
while True:
    if some_condition():
         do_lots_of_stuff_here()
```

I'd use:

```
while True:
    if not some_condition():
        continue
    do_lots_of_stuff_here() # all the code here is less indented this time
```

Comment: thank you so much for replying..... actually I removed "continue" and it's worked the way that I want but I can't understand it in the theoretically way.... i know by removing "continue" it's all good but I learned continue this way.

Comment: I'm glad it has helped you. I've updated my answer with a little example of what kind of situation you'd want to use `continue` in. It's almost never *necessary*, but it can help reduce the amount of indentation needed for complicated loops.

Comment: Thanks. very helpful.